# Failed to create temporary file for /com/sun/jna/win32-x86/jnidispatch.dll library: system can't find path

Tags: java, vba, ms-access, path, temporary-files

I run a java programm via a .cmd-file. I am trying to make ms-access using VBA to call this cmd-file.

Now java runs into a java error, showing: Failed to create temporary file for /com/sun/jna/win32-x86/jnidispatch.dll library: system can't find path

When I run the .CMD-file seperate from VBA first, It returns no error. After one time running, it also runs without any problem via VBA calling the .cmd.

Have tried calling .cmd via:

```
Call Shell(YYYY.cmd, vbnormalfocus)
```

And via:

```
Sub CMDAanroepen()
    Dim wsh As Object
    Set wsh = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Dim waitOnReturn As Boolean: waitOnReturn = False
    Dim windowStyle As Integer: windowStyle = 1
    Dim yourCommand As String

    yourCommand = "YYYY.cmd"

    wsh.Run "cmd /S /K" & yourCommand

End Sub
```

When I restart my computer, the problem arrises again.

It's not my java program, just simply trying to run it. Have found several internet pages regarding this error, but because of the VBA function calling it, I am not sure whether those questions are related.

Please advice.

CMD-file containing:

```
SET USR=user
SET CLASSPATH=.\yyyyy.jar
java -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=zzzz.keystore com.router.router.router.Router -user:%USR% etc.
```

Have also tried to include (not sure if needed) JNA library by changing classpath to:

```
SET CLASSPATH=".;.\yyyyy.jar;.\jna-4.5.2.jar"
```

Comment: How do you call .CMD in VBA ?

Comment: @4dmonster have edited the question to show you!

Comment: may be there is some problems with current directory. Try to add `chdir "path to CMD file"` before call to shell

Comment: @4dmonster have added that line and didn't change the problem.

Comment: @4dmonster do you have any other suggestions:?

Comment: i can only suggest to set `CLASSPATH` variable in CMD file with absolute path.